# Mysqli Connection Error

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, mysqli

> ```
> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object
> ```

So im trying to save some information from a Form to my database, but getting this error when trying to save!, hes the code of mysql connection

```
<?php
$mysql_host     = "localhost";
$mysql_username = "mydb";
$mysql_password = "db";
$mysql_database = "mydbase";

$mysqli  = new Mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
$prepare = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `datos`(`name`,`email`,`phone`,`zipcode`,`message`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
$prepare->bind_param("ssssss", $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['zipcode'], $_POST['message']);
$prepare->execute();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Im trying to figure out but cant make it! Thanks!

Comment: For one thing, your `ssssss` = 6 and your POST values = 5 // remove one `s`

Comment: On top of what Fred said, you should probably do `sssis` because zip code will always be an integer right?

Comment: Try to add `echo mysqli_error($mysqli);` after line `$prepare = $mysqli->prepare` - probably not correct sql for table definition.

Comment: @Arian, zip+4 codes are not an integer, nor are postal codes in Canada or many other countries.

Comment: @Arian: There's a piece of wisdom you occasionally hear about storing things in a database that goes "learn how to tell the difference between a number, and something that looks like a number." For example, a phone number isn't really an integer... In the U.S., it is a 10 character long identifier that just **happens** to be composed of numerical digits. The same can be said for post codes, credit card numbers, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Your `ssssss` = 6 and your `$_POST` values = 5

- remove one of the `s`

However, depending on how your DB/field is setup, as [Arian stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006410/mysqli-connection-error#comment29788825_20006410) may need to be `sssis`

Try either/or.

In certain cases this may not be required, yet they must match in numbers `5 & 5` *for your code.*

Answer (score 1):

This is not a connection error but prepare error. Add these lines at the top

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

and see what it says

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Column count doesn't match value count at row 1` Thats what i get as error!

Comment: this is apparently not for this query. check the query that throws this error